# How to find the next prime within $k$ steps?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**CLAIM**

Noticed a pattern for primes $p \ge 5$ and $q \ne 11$, every $q$ is of the form

$\large q= \left \lfloor \frac{p+5}{q} \right \rfloor$

Define the remainder $k$ as

$\large k = (p+5) \mod q$

Notice that $p$ can be written as

$\large p = q^2-5 + k$

where $3\le k\lt q$

**EXAMPLE**

Let $q=79$, then

$\large p = 79^2 -5+ k = 6236+k$

The next prime $p$ is within $3\le k\lt q$ steps and by checking primality, it finds $k=11$

```
p = 6236 + 3
p = 6236 + 4
p = 6236 + 5
...
p = 6236 + 11 <--- 6247 is prime.
```

**QUESTION**

Tested all primes up to $q=37619$ ($k=3$, $p=1415189159$), perhaps the claim fails with larger $q$ primes?

It would be nice to let $q=2^{82589933} - 1$, the largest known prime, then know that a prime follows

$p=(2^{82589933} - 1)^2 - 5 + k$

within $k$ small steps. ;)

Comment: Not sure what the claim is.  Are you saying that, for any prime $q$ (other than $11$) there is another prime $p$ such that $q=\big \lfloor \frac {p+5}{q}\big \rfloor$?

Comment: Assuming I am reading it correctly, there are a lot of conjectures about primes near $n^2$.  For instance, [Opperman's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture) would guarantee a prime between $q^2$ and $q^2+q$ (for any $q$, not necessarily prime).  Nobody knows how to prove things like that, though there is considerable numerical evidence.

Comment: I wanted to find a prime that was known to be only $k$ steps away from a given starting number.

Comment: Right, where $k$ is (roughly) $q$.  So that's exactly what (that part of) Opperman addresses (there's a small shift, but still). As I said, nobody knows how to attach such questions.  Even the comparatively simpler conjecture of Legendre ("there is always a prime between consecutive squares") is too hard for current techniques.

Comment: @lulu Somewhat related. Although Legendre's conjecture is not proven, it is now known that when $n$ is large, there will always be primes between $n^3$ and $(n+1)^3$, and there is always an almost prime of order 2 between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$. Moreover, there is an infinite number of $n$ such that $n^2+1$ has $\le2$ prime factors.

Comment: If a given prime $p$ is large it is a challenge to find the next prime number. We can only sieve out small factors and test the remaining candidates. The best proven upper bound for the gap to the next prime is $p^{0.525}$ for sufficiently large $p$ , but this is almost surely a very weak bound. $\ln(p)^2$ has not been refuted, if I am informed right.